# what to contextually include in "index.php" for a forum (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmyadmin, forum

Been trying my hands at just setting up something quick and easy to get a look of how a PHP forum would look like and how the thing works in general, following [this handy guide!](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188) Everything's been going quite well, in the sense of reading through the code and writing it over myself bit by bit. However, I have a trouble with "index.php", which is mentioned as a required php file, but it lacks a walkthrough or window of code describing what should be included in the file.

I've tried my hands at just doing "include '*x*.php'" a bunch, thinking maybe it'd be like an empty canvas, but to no avail. Any ideas or help? I really don't know what to put on this thing! Every file I have (excluding index.php) is written exactly as specified on the guide page.

Comment: What do you want in your index file? Forums used to have things like a news section, an about us section, top posting users, most popular threads, etc

Comment: index.php is merely a resource that your (properly configured) web server may know to look for and pass to the PHP engine. It's a bit unclear what you are asking, so maybe you can [edit] this question and put more details about what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you got.